# Cakephp 3 create entry, set custom primary field

Tags: php, cakephp, key

I have a `roles` table. Looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `roles` (
  `role` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `permissions` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE `roles`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`role`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `role` (`role`);
```

Now cake is not recognizing it as a "normal" field, so it doesn't give out any input field.

I fixed my view with this:

```
// src/Template/Admin/Roles/add.ctp

echo $this->Form->control('name', ['class' => 'form-control']);
```

And now the workaround in my controller:

```
// src/Controller/Admin/RolesController.ctp

$roleData = $this->request->getData();
$roleData['role'] = strtolower($roleData['name']);
unset($roleData['name']);

$role = $this->Roles->patchEntity($role, $roleData);
if ($this->Roles->save($role)) {
    $this->Flash->success(__('The role has been saved.'));
}
```

It saves the entry, but doesn't fill up anything in the database row `role`. Am I missing something?

Comment: do you check the `RoleEntity` file in Entity folder, is it accessible!

Comment: What do you do when you need to rename a role? And how would you go about that when there are foreign key constraints? btw, primary keys are required to be unique by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using patchEntity then you cannot assign non assignable fields and your primary key is more than likely not an assignable key by default. You can change it in the entity which should allow the form to show it will allow patch entity to work correctly.

```
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class Role extends Entity
{
    protected $_accessible = [
        'role' => true,
        'permissions' => true,
        '*' => false,
    ];
}
```

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#changing-accessible-fields

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#mass-assignment

Comment: At first try, it didn't work. Then I rebaked the model, controller and views. Now it works. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

In `RolesTable.php` there should be something like this:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);
    $this->setTable('roles');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('role');
}
```

so CakePHP would use `'role'` as PrimaryKey.